# Uncaught TypeError: 'download' is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fluid

I have this button on my page, which points to the function `download()`:

```
<a class="myButton" onclick='return download(this);'>Download</a>
```

**download():**

```
function download(button)
{
  console.info(button);
  return true;
}
```

After clicking the button I get:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: download is not a function
>     at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (mbnet.html:1153)
> ```

However, If I open the developer console and execute `download` then I get:

```
function download(button)
{
  console.info(button);
  return true;
}
```

If I execute `download()` then I get:

```
undefined
true
```

So obviously the function is defined, why am I seeing this error?
Is it because I render the button with fluid?

I also tried to wrap the function `download()` with `$(document).ready();`,
but this changed nothing.

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {

    function download(button)
    {
      console.info(button);
      return true;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Please change the function name , it will work.

Comment: It seems that problem is in function name. 'Download' is reserved word? Tested with changed function name - it works, with 'download', doesn't. :)

Comment: @Ryad.iv, no, without any other js code, download() doesn't work, simple.

Comment: I changed it to `download1` and it works! If I execute `download` in the console now, then I get `VM5344:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: download is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: @sinisake can you explain why ????

Comment: @Ryad.iv, no, i don't have idea. I can't see download in list of reserved words...

Comment: @Satpal, thanks, just checked it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change the function name.

```
<html>
<script>
function download1(button)
{
  console.info(button);
  return true;
}
</script>
<body>
    <a class="myButton" onclick='download1(this);'>Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed it to download1 and it works! If I execute download in the console now, then I get `VM5344:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: download is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1`

So it seems like `download` is not even reserved ?! Is this a strange browser bug?

Comment: \*laugh\*......